# Getting two elements with same ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get two `<a>` elements' values but jQuery is only getting and appending the first one.

```
$bahisleriCek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bahis");
while ($bahisleriCekx = mysql_fetch_array($bahisleriCek)){


echo "<div id='tekbahis'";
echo "Bahis İsim: " . $bahisleriCekx['isim'] . "<br>";
echo "Evet Oranı: " . "<a onclick='evetOranGonder()' href='#' id='evetoran' >" . $bahisleriCekx['evetoran'] . "</a><br>";
echo "<hr>";
echo "</div>";
?>

<script>
function evetOranGonder(){

var evetoran=$("#evetoran").text();

$("#kupon").append(evetoran + '<br>');

}

</script>

<?

}
```

I tried to create a numeric variable which contains loop number and tried to put it next to my ids', but then jQuery only selected the last one.

How can I get all elements' inside values and append them? Thank you.

Comment: Having two elements with the same ID is invalid HTML (an ID represents one object/element), which is why jquery/etc don't really support it.

Comment: Elements shouldn't have the same ID.

Comment: I tried with class, but then it selected all and appended them. I want to append only the one that user selects.

Comment: @Ece You can filter out classes you don't want by choosing a single  class item using [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and specifying an index.

Comment: @Eco in that case you are looking to assign unique IDs per iteration.

Comment: I tried with unique IDs, too. By putting the script inside the while loop and giving a numeric variable inside. But then it selected the last one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Valid HTML dictates that IDs should be unique.  As a work around you can do

```
$('[id="value"]')
```

But ideally you should fix your markup.  If your wanting to 'group' fields by an identifier use a class instead.

```
<a ... class="mylinks">...</a>
```

Then to select them all.

```
$('.mylinks')
```

It appears your trying to select the element the event happened upon.  In which case, in an event handler the keyword 'this' will reference the element the handler is acting upon.

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    //the following line would take the element that was clicked and append it to something else.
    $(someOtherElementSelector).append(this);
});
```

Comment: I tried with class, but then it selected all and appended them. I want to append only the one that user selects.

Comment: $(".evetoran").on('click', function (){
    $("#kupon").append($(this).text());
});

I changed your code to mine, and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ID is called that way with a reason - it should be unique so it can identify an element. You may want to use 'name' instead, and then get all elements with a specified name by using document.getElementsByName - it returns an array. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp